# Run series of commands in different tabs in conemu

Tags: command-line, conemu

I have a `.bat` file which used to open 3 cmd windows each a different colour. I am now using conemu and would like to now do the same but in different tabs. How do I do that?

My `.bat` file:

```
cd /D x:\mercurial\blah\blah
start cmd /k color 4C
cd /D x:\mercurial\blah\blah\solr
start cmd /k color 5D 
cd /D x:\mercurial\blah\blah\rep
start cmd /k color 2A
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Danack - Seriously? Others seemed to understand it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run this from your batch file (one-line command)

```
start "Three tabs" "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe" /cmdlist ^> cmd /k color 4C -cur_console:d:x:\mercurial\blah\blah ^|^|^| cmd /k color 5D -cur_console:d:x:\mercurial\blah\blah\solr ^|^|^| cmd /k color 2A -cur_console:d:x:\mercurial\blah\blah\rep
```

This starts new ConEmu window with three tabs, first tab will be active. `start "Three tabs" ...` is just an example usage of `start` command.

Comment: Perfect, creates exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Works perfect. Worth noting that if you'd like to run a command once in the directory you need to add it after each /k flag. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

To do this from a batch file, try the */cmd* switch. See [the conemu cmdline reference](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Command_Line) for more info.

e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files\Far Manager\ConEmu64.exe" /single /cmd "cmd /k cd c:\symbols"
```

To do this from the **New Console Dialog** see below:
[image: New Console Dialog]

To launch a new tab from an existing conemu tab, see the [-new_console](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/NewConsole) switch.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to open new tabs using my .bat example?

Comment: @Neil added one.

Comment: Sorry I'm useless with cmd stuff, I've tried adding this to "new console dialog" with path to my conemu exe and path but it fails

Comment: @Neil I've nows showed you three ways to do it.

Comment: I have upvoted you, but accepted Maximus' answer as it is perfect for what i needed, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had terrible try making it work. Perhaps it is because I am using **Cmder** or one of my settings. Eventually I wrote the following script that does exactly that - Opens 3 tabs, both in single window using vertical split:

`ConEmu.exe /single /cmd cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat & cd www & npm start" -cur_console:s50V:n:t:"web"
ConEmu.exe /single /cmd cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat & cd server & api.py" -cur_console:s50V:n:t:"backend"
ConEmu.exe /single /cmd cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat & cd c:\nginx\ & nginx" -cur_console:s50V:n:t:"nginx"
ConEmu.exe /single /cmd cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" -new_console:t:"cmd"
sleep 1
exit`

Some notes:

- The script must be run from within a ConEmu tab
- `%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat` needed to initialize Cmder's pretty shell
- Optional: `sleep 1 & exit` closes the tab that initiated the script.

Answer (score -1):

This solution uses **Cmder** which is a packaged version of **ConEmu** with additional enhancements.

The following command opens three different tabs split into 3 panes, with different colored tabs and different working directories set.

```
start "Three Tabs" ConEmu /cmdlist ^> cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat & color 4C & cd C:\Temp" -cur_console:n:t:"Tab 1" ^|^|^| cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat & color 5D & cd c:\" -cur_console:s1T60Hn:t:"Tab2" ^|^|^| cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat & cd C:\Projects" -cur_console:s2T50Vn:t:"Tab 3"
```

- The script must be run from Cmder, it will open a ConEmu session
- `%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat` initializes the Cmder shell
- `color 4C` will set the background and foreground colors
- `cd C:\Temp` sets the working directory per tab

```
Color attributes are specified by TWO hex digits -- the first
corresponds to the background; the second the foreground.  Each digit
can be any of the following values:

    0 = Black       8 = Gray
    1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
    2 = Green       A = Light Green
    3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
    4 = Red         C = Light Red
    5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
    6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
    7 = White       F = Bright White
```

[Split tabs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUXiK.png)

Comment: There might be an answer here, but it’s hard to tell through all the smoke. What is `init.bat`?  Where does this set the working directories (that the question asks for)?  Where does this set the colors (that the question asks for)?  Can you explain what this does and how it works? … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.