# ConEmu - enter command in all visible panels at once

Tags: conemu

Similar to Terminator console tool on Linux https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89471/124930 I wish to type simultaneously commands on Windows into opened ConEmu consolas
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To type in command simultaneously in visible opened panels default shortcut is
<kbd>App</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
BTW app button http://conemu.github.io/en/AppsKey.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run pre-scripted commands this might work: 
[Run series of commands in different tabs in conemu](https://superuser.com/questions/593612/run-series-of-commands-in-different-tabs-in-conemu)

Alternatively MobaXterm (https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) has a MultiExec option to run the same command in multiple windows.